# How to disable Multiple Keyring Popups?

Tags: password, keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unlock keyring promts three times instead one time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7578/unlock-keyring-promts-three-times-instead-one-time)

Whenever I turn on my computer, I would expect the keyring to ask for my password once. But it asks it 3 different times and for the same Default key ring. It really annoys me. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you changed your user's password after you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: This is a duplicate of question 7578: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7578/unlock-keyring-promts-three-times-instead-one-time