# When I boot, I have to log in 3 to 5 times

Tags: login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unlock keyring promts three times instead one time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7578/unlock-keyring-promts-three-times-instead-one-time)

There is always 2 email logins (I have 2 Cox accounts) and 2 keyring logins. I am the only user in a family environment, no other people have access. There must be a way to log in only once. Any help??